# (Python) Program to read specific data from many output files

Tags: python

I recently ran a simulation that output temporal data in directories numbered `0`, `0.1`, `0.2`, ... , `10`.

Within each of these directories there is a text file called `rigidMotion` which contains a line I want to read.

The line looks like:

```
centreOfRotation (0.000 0.000 0.000) //
```

where the numbers vary of course.

I would then like only the numbers to be sent to a text file or a csv file so I can plot them.

Given that its the same line in each file I was trying to use linecache but I'm not sure how to set up the for loop to read each directory.

Comment: Read the files in a Loop, then maybe apply some regex on the content, i.e. `^centreOfRotation (.+)` in multiline mode and grab the first group. Or, read the text line-wise and use `startswith()`.

Comment: Great regex would work well. But how do I set up a loop to run through these files? It would be great if I could just go: for (int i = 0; i <=10; i + 0.1) then use open for filename/i but that wouldnt work of course.

Comment: @Bruce see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the directory reading this worked for me the best in multiple directories:

```
import os

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk("your root directory"):
    for file in files:
        print os.path.join(subdir, file)
        #processing the files
```

For the line processing i would use string trimming if only the numbers change in it.

```
trimmedString = originalString[a:-b]
```

where 'a' is the last index what you want to cut from the beginning, and 'b' is for the ending, in your case:

a = the index of the opening bracket

b = index of the closing bracket

Answer (score 2):

You can use [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) to find files according to a pattern, which in your case might be something like `*/rigidMotion`, then iterate over those files and collect the values, outputting them to a new file.